# Why is OOMKilled pod not getting ready when rescheduled?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a error with unhealty pod even though I think the pod works as expected after reschduling. If I restart (delete) it, it becomes ready but I would like to understand why it ends up in a unhealty state.

My probe is simple as this:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 4000
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 30
```

Events:

```
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                                        Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                                        -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  99s (x2253 over 35h)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-23887969-vmss000000  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.142:4000/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

State & Last state

```
  State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 17 Apr 2020 19:44:58 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 17 Apr 2020 00:20:31 +0200
      Finished:     Fri, 17 Apr 2020 19:44:56 +0200
    Ready:          False
```

If I run

```
 kubectl exec -t other pod -- curl -I 10.244.0.142:4000/
```

I get 200 OK

Can someone explain why pod not gets ready? I guess it has something to do with OOMKilled because of Memory limit, and that should be fixed. But I would like to understand why it doesn´t restart propery.

Comment: pod got oom killed so probe did not pass...but what is the question?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I think that pod got killed Fri, 17 Apr 2020 19:44:56, got restarted Fri, 17 Apr 2020 19:44:58. It is ready and works when I get with curl. Question is why it doesn´t get the ready status?

Comment: okay so it works as expected but the Ready is still false

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes, I can verify that with both curl from other pod and port-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Oomkilled is the previous state. The current state is running (Ready). The problem is the readiness probe.

Comment: Yes, but what can the error with that probe be? it answers on IP:PORT/ when I request with curl

Comment: Some common issues: if you need any headers make sure you add them, make sure it works with localhost, make sure it works with default compression/encoding.